# Rendering models in template which are related themselves

Tags: python, html, django

I write a twitter-like app in django,
I've got two models:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Replies(models.Model):
    reply = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reply
```

And the fragment of template:

```
{% block content %}
            {% for t in tweets %}
            <table class="table1">
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @{{t.user}}
                        <br> <br>
                        {{t.content}}
                        <br> <br>
                        {{t.creation_date}}
                    </td>
                    #######
 
                    #######
                </tr>
            </table>
            {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Between '####' i would like to have all the replies to the specific tweet, how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just include views.py also then it will more meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do the trick:

```py
{% block content %}
            {% for t in tweets %}
            <table class="table1">
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @{{t.user}}
                        <br> <br>
                        {{t.content}}
                        <br> <br>
                        {{t.creation_date}}
                    </td>
                    {% for reply in t.replies_set.all %}
                    {{reply.user}} {{reply.reply}}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is a link to the documentation that explains many to one relationships in detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 1):

@Steffen - it works, however you need to remove '()' at the end of

```
for reply in t.replies_set.all()
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad that did it for you! I've edited the answer.